# If I add a comment to my answer will the asker be notified?

Tags: support, answers, comments, notifications

If I add a comment to my answer will it notify the asker even though

1. I haven't used the @user attribute
2. The asker hasn't commented on that answer previously

Comment: duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: Is this off-topic in this meta?

Comment: @SmartManoj No. But it seems to be a duplicate (of a post on meta.stackexchange though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, no.

Servy has already linked you to [the master FAQ on the global Meta that explains how comment replies work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but it does not appear that a similar FAQ exists here, so I'll summarize it for you.

*The rules appear fairly complex, but they are fundamentally quite simple and designed to do what is desirable in the vast majority of cases.*

**The cardinal rule is** that you can *only* use @replies in comments to notify people who have previously interacted with a post. That interaction includes the author of the post, anyone who has previously left a comment, and anyone who has edited the post (although their user names won't be auto-completed).

So, you cannot notify the asker by commenting on an answer if they haven't previously commented on that answer. You can, however, notify the answerer. If you want to notify the asker, comment on the *question*, instead.

If you don't use the @reply syntax, only the author of the post will be notified (or, if you are the author, and there is only one previous commenter, they will be notified).

Comment: Also close voters can be @notified.